# Javascript JSON serialize only first level

Tags: c#, javascript, json, angularjs, entity-framework

I am building an application using AngularJS on the client, and ASP.NET WebAPI/Entity Framework on the back end.

Instead of relying on purely RESTful services, I need to ensure that complete transactions are either stored or rolled back. Therefore, I have written a JavaScript UnitOfWork implementation, that tracks each of my loaded objects, and stores them separately per type.

I am running into an issue when persisting them.

Imagine I have the following object loaded through a web API:

```
{
    FirstName: "Bob",
    LastName: "Jensen",
    Email: "test@example.com",
    Country: { ID: 61, Name = "Zimbabwe"},
    CountryID: 61,
    Animals: [
        { Name: "Mittens", ID: 2},
        { Name: "Rex", ID: 1}
    ]
}
```

Now, let's say that I change Bobs LastName and want to save that. I send my UoW to the server, and on the EF Context, I do the following on my edited object (no code touching obj until this point):

```
databaseContext.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

This gives me an error like this:

> Attaching an entity of type 'MyApp.Model.Country' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

My first thought is to strip away the unwanted properties before sending it back to the server - so in my above JSON, I should send a similar result back, but sans the 'Country' and 'Animals' properties. I still want to keep CountryID.

1. Is this possible without explicitly specifying which properties to delete?
2. Is there something conceptually wrong with my approach since I am facing this issue? Should I handle this server-side instead?

Comment: I bet your context's lifespan is too long.

Comment: Hm.. That is actually an interesting point that I hadn't even considered. It is stored in a private field on my ASP.NET controller. I must admit that I hadn't considered how often a controller was instantiated, and just kind of assumed it was once per request. I take it I was mistaken, and will look into this tomorrow. Thanks! Still, I'd prefer not to serialize the entire object graph for each UnitOfWork I'd like to send.

Comment: @GertArnold: I checked, and no - my controller is getting instantiated on each request, so my content only lives for one query/action.

Comment: Yes, that's the default behavior in MVC. But somehow this entity gets attached before the line you show. Could you show some surrounding code?

Comment: how did you fetch the obj? I saw somewhere that there are methods to fetch it from the db which will already mark it as modified, so you just need to update the data and not touch the state

Comment: @GertArnold: I tried changing the line to: new DatabaseContext().Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified; Same result.

Comment: @Etai: The object comes from JSON in my client. There is no link back to the EF context that created it, so it shouldn't be attached. Please note that it is not complaining about 'obj', but about one of the many-to-ones on this object.

Comment: What happens in `DatabaseContext`'s constructor?

Comment: @GertArnold: Nothing: public DatabaseContext() : base("WindowsServer") { }. It is just an EF DbContext. It holds nothing but my DbSets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working by removing the collection and object references on my JavaScript object:

```
var clone = {};
for (prop in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[prop] == "string" || typeof obj[prop] == "number" || typeof obj[prop] == "boolean") {
        clone[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
}
```

Now EF is happy, and I save a minuscule amount of bandwidth by not sending the entire graph.